# How to push array to state several times in react native SetState?

Tags: react-native, setstate

I would like to push several arrays to the same state(array) like below.

```
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  itemsArray1: [],
  itemsArrayMixed: [],
 }
}


handleSetState1() {
 this.setState({ 
  itemsArray1: [
   {name: 'aaa', id: '001', address: 'xxx' },
   {name: 'aaa', id: '002', address: 'yyy'},
   {name: 'ccc', id: '003', address: 'zzz'},
  ]
 });

 this.setState({ itemsArrayMixed: [...itemsArray1] });

}

handleSetState2() {
 this.setState({ 
  itemsArray1: [
   {name: 'ddd', id: '004', address: 'ttt' },
   {name: 'eee', id: '005', address: 'uuu'},
   {name: 'fff', id: '006', address: 'www'},
  ]
 });

 this.setState({ itemsArrayMixed: [...itemsArray1] });

}

console.log(itemsArrayMixed) // => in itemsArrayMixed,  I want to get 6 objects.
```

Above code is just an example.

In my project, I import 6 arrays that include objects from a different store.
And I want to push all these arrays to the same state (in this case, itemsArrayMixed).

Of course, if I want to handle only one array, that's easy to handle and I know how to do that.

However, I don't know how to push multi arrays to the same state...

Comment: Won't the following work? this.setState({ itemsArrayMixed: [...itemsArray1,... itemsArray2] });

Comment: I would like to use only one state like itemsArray1.

Comment: That's what I tried to write... Obviously I don't understand what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding the new array(itemsArray1) in the mixed array without getting its previous value. you should try this and it will work

```
handleSetState1() {
  let itemArray1 = [
    {name: 'aaa', id: '001', address: 'xxx' },
    {name: 'aaa', id: '002', address: 'yyy'},
    {name: 'ccc', id: '003', address: 'zzz'},
   ]
  this.setState({ 
   itemsArray1 
  });
  this.setState({ itemsArrayMixed: [...this.state.itemsArrayMixed, itemArray1] });
}
```

This will update the itemArrayMixed and store all value.